# SSRS(rdl file) How to add multiple expressions to one text box

Tags: reporting-services, expression, rdl

When choosing a textbox in rdl design file - you can add expression. But how do I add multiple expressions to the same textbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click in the text box until you get the cursor (usually 1st click
   will select the text box, the 2nd will place the cursor in it).
2. Next, right-click the cell and choose `Create Placeholder`
3. Set the  expression for the placeholder as you would for a textbox.
4. Now you can also type literals into the text box and then right-click again when you need another place holder
5. Repeat as required...

I often use this for things like page numbers with a total that might look like this...

[image]

**Note**: You can format each piece of text individually too using this method.